# protractor iframe inside an iframe inside an iframe

Tags: testing, iframe, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

I'm trying to get to controls inside a frame that is located inside a frame that is located inside another frame.

The last (deepest) frame is used only for login - that I manage to do.

The problem is that after the login I basically need to return to the upper frame and click a button. For some reason I keep getting the error:

> NoSuchElementError: no such element

BTW, all the code in the frames is non-angular.

This is my code for the test:

```
it('Should get to drive sample app', function () {
  login.get();
  login.clickLogin();

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

  login.goToUsecases();  //getting to the page
  $('[href="/developers/api/1542"]').click();
  browser.sleep(5000);
  //iframe issue starts here
  browser.switchTo().frame(0);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.switchTo().frame(0);
  browser.switchTo().frame(0);

  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("username");
  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("password");
  browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click();

  // login succeeded 
  browser.sleep(10000);
  browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('home')).click();
  browser.sleep(10000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that after the login I basically need to return to the upper frame and click a button.

From what I see in your code, you are switching to the default content, but, as you said, the button is inside the upper iframe, switch to it:

```
browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
browser.switchTo().frame(0);
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('home')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this may be this helps you.. As this works for me for handling different windows.

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

```
newWindowHandle = handles[1];

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {

    browser.sleep(500).then(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName_str')).sendKeys("username");

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("password");

        browser.driver.findElement(by.name('submit')).click();
```

//login succeeded 
        });

```
    //to close the current window
    browser.driver.close().then(function () {
        //to switch to the previous window
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[0])
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('home')).click()
        browser.sleep(10000);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: It is not about windows, but frames.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ::browser.switchTo().frame(0);

try giving the locate of the iframe where you want to switch too.. that might help.

// Switch to iframe context in order to see inside iframe
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe')));